# Liferay: extend custom-jsp by html-form and own action

Tags: hook, liferay

I would like to extend a liferay core jsp by custom-jsp hook. In this extensions I add new html-form in the jsp so, that submitting this html-form should call my action-class.
However, how can I call my Action-Class from customizing jsp?

Comment: are you trying to execute code from a different (custom) portlet? Where/how is your action implemented? For Struts see the answer by Martin. If this is for a specific portlet, it might help to actually name where you have the problem. Otherwise it might serve as an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not posible to add new Action class by the hook and refer to this from jsp that are customized from the same hook. Because the Action class and the custom jsp will be load from different class loader. New Action class will be load by portlet (hook) class loader, elsewise custom jsp will be load by the Root class loader.

The only way out is to create the ext-plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Liferay's blog entry [Overriding and adding struts actions from hook plugin](http://www.liferay.com/web/mika.koivisto/blog/-/blogs/7132115)

It should answer your question.